# How to deprecate a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

For background to this, please see [Sage accounting software tag as opposed to sagemath](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139946/sage-accounting-software-tag-as-opposed-to-sagemath)

I would like to create a new tag (apparently I finally have enough rep to do so!) for [sagemath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sagemath), because of the ambiguity problem and because Sage is now indeed also calling itself [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/).  So far, so good.

But this is pointless if there is still a [sage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage) tag hanging around, especially one that is so ambiguous.  I don't see any [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) on how to deprecate a tag/make it unusable, nor did searching on this forum bring up that particular thing.  Maybe it's only possible for SE employees?

Edit: Apparently I was not clear enough on why I think this is necessary.  I spend far too much time retagging the accounting software "sage" questions into [sage-erp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage-erp) or [sagepay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sagepay) (for ones that seem British).  I think that merging would not solve this problem at all, which is why I'm asking about deprecation.  Naturally, one could also create `sagemath`, but that wouldn't resolve the ambiguity issue.

Comment: Although there is such a thing for making a tag "unusable" without deleting it, it is only utilized for horrible and big tags and can only be done by moderators or developers (not sure which). I suggest you think about a [meta-tag:burninate-request]. 300 questions is doable for 2 or 3 people retagging stuff. I suggest that you wait to do this until you get 2000 rep so that your edits don't go into the review queues.

Comment: There are only just over 300 questions to be migrated.  That's definitely doable.  The precedent question from what's now MSE could have dealt with it 3 years ago, when the number of questions was smaller — oh well, it is easy to be wise after the event (and maybe the reputations weren't large enough before to be able to do it).

Comment: Yeah, I could probably hand-migrate things at some point.  Yet another "wrong Sage" cropped up today... sigh.  I'll look into the burninate thing, though it seems so '05.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Burnination? Retag? Cleanup?

Comment: I guess I was asking for info about all options.

Answer (score 12):

As someone who follows [sage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage) tag (apparently, I'm the [top user over 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sage/topusers) :), I don't see any ambiguity in its *actual use*. It is so consistently used for SageMath software that it's fair to say: in the context of Stack Overflow, [sage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage) means SageMath. Removing this perfectly useful tag isn't needed.

The tags [sage-erp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage-erp) and [sage-crm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage-crm) do exist, but have much less use than [sage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage).

But you make a good point that the software is now called SageMath. Perhaps the tag should be renamed to acknowledge this. New  questions that someone attempts to tag [sage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage) should still be mapped to SageMath by default.

Comment: Pretty sure just renaming the tag would be best, as then that leaves a big obvious lack of [tag:sage] when someone tries to use it... which points them to the tags that *are* there: [tag:sagemath] and so forth.

Comment: Renaming is not really a thing that happens. We can [synonymize](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sage/synonyms) the two, making them equivalent for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @Dukeling Merging [tag:sage] into [tag:sagemath] (without creating a synonym) would be functionally equivalent to renaming the tag. Although a mod would be needed to perform this action.

Comment: @Normal Human - I understand your point, see my edit to my question which I hope will clarify this.

Comment: @Dukeling note that merging one tag into another without a syn is effectively a rename...

Answer (score 3):

1. Alternatively, can the tag [sage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage) be **renamed** [sagemath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sagemath)?

   1.a. That would clearly distinguish the various software called Sage:

   - [sage-erp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage-erp), [sage50](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage50), [sage-300](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage-300), [sage-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage-one),
     [sagepay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sagepay) for various accounting software by Sage Group PLC,
   - [roots-sage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roots-sage) for the WordPress starter theme by roots.io,
   - [sagemath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sagemath) for SageMath, the Sage mathematics software system.

   1.b. The Sage mathematics software system is called SageMath for
     disambiguation.

   See the dedicated wiki pages on SageMath's wiki:

   - https://wiki.sagemath.org/FromSageToSageMath
   - https://wiki.sagemath.org/ThingsCalledSage

   1.c. Another StackExchange site uses tag [sagemath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sagemath) for SageMath:

   - https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sagemath

   1.d. Admittedly, other StackExchange sites use [sage] for SageMath,
   but if there tags can be renamed, I volunteer to propose a renaming
   throughout the StackExchange network of sites. Although there is no
   ambiguity with the tag [sage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage) on sites such as MathOverflow.
2. Could tags listed in (1.a) have their description hint at each other?

   2.a. This could be by including something like the list in (1.a)
     in the tag description of each tag listed in (1.a).
3. Can StackOverflow's tag autocompletion and search be **improved**?

   3.a. Currently, when searching "sage" among StackOverflow tags at
   https://stackoverflow.com/tags,

   - 36 results are displayed
   - not all tags listed in (1.a) are among these 36 results
   - many "message-something" or "something-message" are suggested
   - there is no indication that more tags exist than the 36 displayed
   - there is no way to access further results beyond the 36 displayed

   3.b. By contrast, autocompletion in a browser's bookmarks favours
   the results including the search item as beginning of a full word,
   therefore it would find all the tags listed in (1.a) above before
   any tag containing "sage" only as part of "message".

Comment: I love 1.a which is essentially my suggestion.  Don't want to burninate yet until that's done.

Comment: If the option to **rename** the tag [tag:sage] to [tag:sagemath] exists, does the tag [tag:sage] survive and become an alias to [tag:sagemath]?

Comment: I think either that or burnination is possible; I'd prefer burnination because of the historical misuse (I still have to retag on a regular basis).